# Parsing of JSON where a key contains spaces

Tags: rest-api, json, string, deserialize

I am trying to deserialize this response

```
{  
   "invoiceList":[  
      {  
         "totalPrice":5.5,
         "statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z",
         "lineItems":[  
            {  
               "UnitPrice":1.0,
               "Quantity":5.0,
               "ProductName":"Pencil"
            },
            {  
               "UnitPrice":0.5,
               "Quantity":1.0,
               "ProductName":"Eraser"
            }
         ],
         "invoiceNumber  ":1
      },
      {  
         "totalPrice":11.5,
         "statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z",
         "lineItems":[  
            {  
               "UnitPrice":6.0,
               "Quantity":1.0,
               "ProductName":"Notebook"
            },
            {  
               "UnitPrice":2.5,
               "Quantity":1.0,
               "ProductName":"Ruler"
            },
            {  
               "UnitPrice":1.5,
               "Quantity":2.0,
               "ProductName":"Pen"
            }
         ],
         "invoiceNumber  ":2
      }
   ]
}
```

here I give invoiceNumber with space.

After deserialize this data I got **invoiceNumber=null**
plz help me this is my code

```
public class ParsingJsonExample2 {
    public string input                    {set;get;}    
    public string output                {set;get;}
    public void getdata(){
        input='{"invoiceList":[{"totalPrice":5.5,"statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z","lineItems":[{"UnitPrice":1.0,"Quantity":5.0,"ProductName":"Pencil"},{"UnitPrice":0.5,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Eraser"}],"invoiceNumber ":1},{"totalPrice":11.5,"statementDate":"2011-10-04T16:58:54.858Z","lineItems":[{"UnitPrice":6.0,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Notebook"},{"UnitPrice":2.5,"Quantity":1.0,"ProductName":"Ruler"},{"UnitPrice":1.5,"Quantity":2.0,"ProductName":"Pen"}],"invoiceNumber ":2}]}';
        fromJSON json2Apex =fromJSON.parse(input);
        system.debug(json2apex);
    }
}
```

inner class:

```
public class fromJSON{
    public cls_invoiceList[] invoiceList;
    public class cls_invoiceList {
        public decimal totalPrice;    
        public Datetime statementDate;    
        public cls_lineItems[] lineItems;
        public Integer invoiceNumber ;    
    }
    class cls_lineItems {
        public decimal UnitPrice;    
        public Decimal Quantity;    
        public String ProductName;    
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON deserialization is case sensitive and needs to match the properties of the Apex class exactly.

Spaces in Apex are ignored, so the line `public Integer invoiceNumber ;` is actually compiled as if it was `public Integer invoiceNumber;`.

So the JSON deserializer is looking for the invoiceNumber field (without the space) and cannot find it, thus assigns it a null value.

If you want to keep this JSON structure, you need to replace `"invoiceNumber "` with `"invoiceNumber"` in the JSON string, before deserializing. Try something like this:

```
public static fromJSON parse(String json){
    return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json.replace('invoiceNumber ', 'invoiceNumber'), fromJSON.class);
}
```